# bash: how to flatten columns in text file?

Tags: bash, text

I have a file like this:

```
foo, bar, foo1
bar, foo
foo
```

I want it like this:

```
foo
bar
foo1
bar
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat file | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d ,
```

If you want to remove empty lines in the stream just add `| grep -xv ''`

If you mean that *columns* are separated with `,`, you can use something like:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/, /\n/g'
```

I must note that that will not work in Mac OS X (thanks to Frost for the tip).
When you are in Mac OS X, you must use another construction that is not so nice:

```
cat file.txt | sed -e 's/, /\'$'\n/g'
```

Comment: Oh, and another comment, since you're actually using sed, why do you use cat to pipe the file into the sed command, instead of just supplying the file as an argument to sed, like so: `sed -e 's/, /\'$'\n/g' file.txt`?

Comment: Just for educational purposes. I just wanted to make the command as more selfdescriptive as possible.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
awk -F ', ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file.txt
```

works for the example you gave (It may have some complications if the comma's not always followed by a space).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/, /\                                                                                                                                                                        
/g' file.txt
```